# How can I make .htaccess file by PHP? If not found .htaccess file in my directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Actually I have created a PHP Script where .htaccess file is required. But problem is that: When I my script on Ipage server, This server don't upload .htaccess file automatically.

Although I can create .htaccess file from server by "Create File" button. In this situation, I want: My script will create automatically .htaccess file, if not found .htaccess file in my directory.

---

*My .htaccess file's code is*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: And the script/ code you used is?

Comment: @SuperDJ which script are used, that is not a fact - I think. I just want to know. If I run index.php file, it willl check .htaccess file exist or not. If not exist - the index.php file will create new .htaccess file automatically.

Comment: How does it know what it has to write into the `.htaccess`?

Comment: ok, my .htaccess file code is:
`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: @SaifulIslam place that code in the question not in a comment

Comment: I have added my script at question. Thanks n advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `bool file_exists ( string $filename )` method to check if the files exists. If not create it and write your contents to it (e.g. using `file_put_contents`).

```
if(!file_exists('.htaccess'))
{
    $content = 'RewriteEngine On' . "\n"
    $content .= 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d' . "\n"
    $content .= 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f' . "\n"
    $content .= 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l' . "\n\n"
    $content .= 'RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]';

    file_put_contents('.htaccess', $content);
}
```

Comment: The PHP5 function [`file_put_contents`](https://secure.php.net/file_put_contents)  is easier, shorter and cleaner. The PHP4 file functions have their existence right, especially when it's about buffered reading and writing. But this question is no such case.

Comment: yup, thanks for the hint